# New to game development

Tags: unity, c#, python

I have some programing experience, and I have tried making some games. I have some knowledge with c#, but I am much better at python. I have a general code structure knowledge, so I am open to learn other languages. I have tried making some demos in Unity.
But my question is where can I get the most resources to start making small games. I'm willing to pay some money for tutorials and software, but "free" is always appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to GameDev.StackExchange. Unfortunately, open-ended requests for tutorials, software, or advice on getting started are considered off-topic here, because they lead to a LOT of duplicated questions with fuzzy criteria, and answers that are quickly out of date. Your best bet for the latest info here is to just do a Google search - there are easily hundreds of tutorials and guides at your fingertips. If you need something very specific that you're having trouble finding yourself, feel free to ask a more specific question.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=where+can+I+get+the+most+resources+to+start+making+small+games

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although I think this is a bit off topic, I know of several places where you can get starting making small games with Unity3D, JavaScript, and Python. Zenva Corp has a plethora of tutorials regarding game development for free, the website to view them is GameDevAcademy.org and it is a great starting resource. Youtube has tons of videos regarding game development which also includes walkthroughs on creating games. Lynda.com and Pluralsight.com are both paid services that have great lesson videos on pretty much everything regarding development. The last place I would suggest is looking through github.com because people upload repositories for games and software they are developing in a variety of languages. Some even use github to host their tutorials on game development.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.